# Schengen Visa from Greece was rejected

Tags: visa-refusals, europe, greece

My Schengen visa was rejected in october 2018 stating:

1. Justification for the purpose and conditions of intended stay was not provided
2. The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of intended stay was not reliable.

Kindly advise what went wrong. This was my first attempt for any visa application. I do not have any travel history and the reason I want to travel now is to redeem a travel voucher I was awarded by my employer.

So I do understand me not adding a cover letter was one of the biggest mistake. Secondly I think I submitted two bank statements...One is for my Salary transfer account where usually I do not maintain any balance and second was my savings account which I usually use for all my transactions. 
So if I now attach the copy of travel voucher and cover letter and my salary account with a good balance and transactions for almost 4 months, will that help?

Comment: See also [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/67978). Although that's about the UK, it applies equally well here.

Comment: There are not only documents (which is good if you provide more of them). You didn't write anything (in this question) about your family, your travel plan (and possibly your job). You should convince that you will come back home, so you should provide some reasons (job, family). Having also a travel plan helps (duration, if you can afford it [two week holidays are different than 4 month around Europe].

Comment: Without any previous travel history, a sensible approach would be to use your travel voucher to visit a country that you can enter visa-free or that has a less stringent visa regime, rather than risk another refusal to add to the one you already have. Repeated refusals can damage your credibility and future travel prospects.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi  i do have my family here and i work for a bank and mentioning i would return back to work is easy but how would i prove the same..We have standard format for NOC where return dates are not mentioned. Travel plans yes i need to work on that.