# Uk visa query About Dependents

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

In Uk visa form, there is one question about dependents.
I'm single and I have mentioned my mother as my dependent in the form..But in UAE i have visa which is sponsored by her. She is not working but my Visa is from her. 
I'm employed and i would be providing all the required documents from my employer.
So would this be an issue mentioning my mother as my dependent which is a fact but then providing residency visa under her name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your mother sponsored your UAE visa as a resident and not as a financial sponsor this shouldn’t be a problem. You can explain the specific circumstances in the ‘Additional information’ section at the end of the application and/or in your covering letter. Providing proof that your mother is dependent on you will help, for example her age, evidence she lives with you, proof that you give her a regular allowance etc.

You’ve recently been refused a Schengen visa [Schengen Visa from Greece was rejected](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134320/schengen-visa-from-greece-was-rejected) and in that question you state that you have no previous travel history. That combination of circumstances is possibly not advantageous to your UK visa application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what sort of proof...She is dependent on me and my siblings but i dont have any proof showing the same.

Comment: I wonder how one can have "no previous travel history", yet be in the UAE and require a visa to be there?

Comment: @traveller So Do u suggest applying fresh application for greece again

Comment: @Saadia lakhany No, I’m suggesting you consider reapplying only after you’ve built up a travel history to other countries with less stringent visa regimes, rather than risk another refusal by reapplying to Greece relatively quickly, or applying to the UK for the first time. But it’s your call.

Comment: @traveller My Schengen Visa got rejected i think firstly because i did not attach a cover letter and second my bank statements were not what was required. That was in October. Now atleast for last 4 months I have a better Bank statement. So should i risk applying for greece..

Comment: @Traveller Secondly after having travel history still i would be rrquired to mention